# Appsync Caching with ApiGateway { message: 'Internal server error' }

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-appsync

Im running into an issue with Appsync and ApiGateway running on NodeJS. I have set up resources that define several endpoints with a passThrough to a rest api. I also have as `Stage` that defines resource paths and enables caching. For example I have a resource with a path matching the following stage `MethodSetting`

```
-   ResourcePath: "/~1v1~1item~1{seasonCode}~1{itemCode}"
    HttpMethod: "GET"
    CacheDataEncrypted: false
    CacheTtlInSeconds: ${self:provider.environment.ITEM_CACHE_TTL}
    CachingEnabled: true
    MetricsEnabled: true
```

It is my understandign that the `ResourcePath` has to match a path in the Resources defined for this ApiGateway deployment. Im then making get requests to the caching/passthrough endpoints on the api deployed for this stage like so:

```
request = {
      hostname: host,
      path: `${pathPrefix}/v1.1/items/${seasonCode}/${itemCode}?policyCode=${
        apiContext.policyCode
      }`,
      headers: apiGatewayHeaders(apiContext)
};
```

All of the stage `MethodSetting`s are returning the following error: `{ message: 'Internal server error' }` from the get request. My understanding is Appsync triggers a lambda for a specific graphql request and that lambda executes the get method. When the lambda calls the get method with the cachign endpoint i get the error above. I am using cloudformation to deploy.

EDIT:

ApiGateway is giving me the following logs in `CloudWatch`,.

```
{
    "requestId": "57526082-dc90-4d51-867f-7cee467deacf",
    "ip": "52.34.128.195",
    "caller": "-",
    "requestTime": "1591741653774",
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "resourcePath": "/v1.1/items/{seasonCode}/{itemCode}",
    "status": "500",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
    "responseLength": "36"
}
```